# Calling a method after each derived class constructor

Tags: c#

I need each class which is derived from abstract class P to call doSomething() after it is constructed. There are many classes derived from P, and there is no consistency as to which parameters are required by the children's constructors. Because there are potentially hundreds of derived classes, I'd like to avoid writing doSomething() explicitly at the end of each child constructor.

How can this be accomplished in a way that doesn't smell? How can this be accomplished at all?

Comment: Sounds kind of [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Comment: I agree, but I haven't worked-out a non-smelly implementation of factory pattern in this case. The variety of child constructor parameters is a hiccup

Comment: The description is too subjective, for me an object type parameter is also acceptable.